# Hover state maintenance between CSS menu and sub-menu

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover, submenu

My question relates to this post: [CSS Space between menu and submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158434/css-space-between-menu-and-submenu)

What I'd like to understand is WHY this particular solution works for the original question. Why does editing the properties of **nav ul ul:before** impact a hover state that seems to be defined as active when hovering over an **li** item in that list? I've used this solution in my own code to great success but don't understand why it works. Is the **li** simply expanding to fill the space of **ul:before**?

Thanks in advance for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

That solution works out because with the `nav ul ul:before` rule that is set in that answer an additional content is set directly before the second ul. It is an empty content with a size of 20px and a top position of -20px. because the second ul is child of the li of the first ul and has no fixed height set, it expands like every other container with `height:auto;` to the height of the content.